# Where do I find the SSH Key to paste on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am following the [GitHub guide on generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys). I'm on [step 3](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-3-add-your-ssh-key-to-github), sub-step 5

> Paste your key into the "Key" field.

How exatly do i find the key? Where do I go to open to then paste it onto GitHub?

I have tried this

```
$ open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
$ ssh-rsa
ssh-rsa: command not found
```

How do I open the `.ssh` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You paste the content of the public key ( `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) you [generated in step 2](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-2-generate-a-new-ssh-key)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

That produced  `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (private key) and  `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (the public key to copy on your GitHub account).

Comment: Thanks. I also just found that `cat id_rsa.pub` displays the key.

Comment: @JonaTheApprentice Yes, I have added the `cat` command in the answer.

Comment: I don't know why I have to wait a certain time to accept the answer.

Comment: @JonaTheApprentice in case a better answer comes along. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44099/6309